# Djikstras Algorithm if it doesn't exist a path

Tags: shortest-path

I wonder if you have a source and a target vertice and that I want to find the shortest path between them. 
My question is it doesn't exist a path between source and target vertrice what will happen then in Djikstras Algorithm will this algorithm discover it?

[Djikstra's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for information which will get you a better response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm will eventually run out of possible paths to check, determining that it is not possible: the distance to the target vertice would still be infinity, as it was initialized.

Not necessarily the best way to determine this, though.

Comment: How will the algortim output it?